# Launching Instance in multiple region

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can we launch an instance in **multiple region** in AWS? I know the concept of Elastic IP or taking a snapshot or copying an IAM. Can we do this in other regions without minimal downtime?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can provide more information about **why** you are asking this question, we may be able to provide better answers. What do you mean by "an instance"? Do you mean an *identical copy* of a virtual machine? How do you intend to send users to it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to launch an EC2 instance in multiple regions. An EC2 instance can only exist in a single availability zone, in a single region.

You can launch multiple copies of your AMI images (EC2 instances) in multiple availability zones, in multiple regions.

Once you have your EC2 instance running in a single availability zones, you can create an AMI image from that EC2 instance and launch copies in other availability zones in the same region. Creating an AMI doesn't have to cause downtime, however, it is recommended to stop the EC2 instance while the AMI image is created. So best to create the AMI image before the EC2 instance needs to be up 100% of the time.

You can also copy that AMI from the original region to another region. Once copied, you can launch new EC2 instances in that second region.

Elastic IP addresses can only be attached to a single EC2 instance in a single region at a time. It is not possible to move or copy Elastic IP addresses between regions.

Comment: Small addition: you can use Route 53 to route traffic to the EC2 instances distributed on multiple regions (latency based, failover, ...).